# What is the hex value for O_APPEND?

Tags: c, linux

fcntl-linux.h shows

```
#ifndef O_APPEND
# define O_APPEND     02000
#endif
```

// sample C code

```
int APPEND_MASK  = O_APPEND;
```

GDB snippit

```
(gdb) print /x APPEND_MASK 
$11 = 0x400
```

I determined that the header file is storing the bit flags in octal via manual conversion but how would I know that otherwise? For instance, where in the header file does it say octal is the number system..?

Comment: Starting an integer literal with `0` means octal.

Comment: It's not in the header file. It's part of the language standard. Numbers starting with a zero not followed by an `x` are octal. Numbers with `0x` are hex.

Comment: Learned something new.. thanks..

Comment: `printf("%x\n", O_APPEND)` maybe?

Answer (score 1):

The header file just defines a macro, which is simple string substitution. So the result of that macro is that

```
int APPEND_MASK = O_APPEND;
```

is replaced with

```
int APPEND_MASK = 02000;
```

In C, when an integer constant begins with `0`, it's interpreted as octal (just as the `0x` prefix means to interpret it as hex). It makes no difference whether the constant is written directly in the C code or comes from a macro in a header.